# Returning two Entity Framework query results together

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

I am a newbie in ASP.NET (CORE) and Entity Framework! I'm trying to return the results of two seperate queries all at once using the code snippet below. QueryToReturn is a class that includes both projectGoal class and projectType class as a List. _context is the DbContext.

```
List<ProjectGoal> projectGoal = new List<ProjectGoal>();
List<ProjectType> projectType = new List<ProjectType>();

projectGoal = _context.ProjectGoal.ToList();
projectType = _context.ProjectTypes.ToList();

QueryToReturn FinalItems = new QueryToReturn();
FinalItems.projectGoal = projectGoal;
FinalItems.projectType = projectType;

return Ok(FinalItems);
```

Am I doing it correctly or I am missing something? How can this be done using LINQ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a class with both Lists and return that.

Comment: As @VDWWD noted, you can create viewmodel with two property then set them. If it is in business layer, you can create DTO

Comment: What is the problem? The code looks like it should work. One note about the _context is that it should be inside a `using var context = etcetc` and dispose, though I obviously can't see what you're actually doing with it.

Comment: @VDWWD he already did. It's called `QueryToReturn`.

Comment: @MarkCiliaVincenti, you are right. I did not see that. But then what is the problem indeed?

Comment: @MarkCiliaVincent In fact it works but I just wanted to make sure this is a correct way of passing the data from two tables.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm right you want to return two classes as lists to your view.

Create an extra class to combine your 2 lists.

Model

```
public class QueryToReturn
{
    public List<ProjectGoal> projectGoal { get; set; }
    public List<ProjectType> projectType { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectGoal
{
    public string somevariable { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectType
{
   public string somevariable2 { get; set; }
}
```

Create an object of your master class and fill the 2 lists with your database content.

Controller

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
        QueryToReturn FinalItems = new QueryToReturn();
        FinalItems.projectGoal = _context.projectGoal.ToList();
        FinalItems.projectType = _context.ProjectTypes.ToList();
        return View(FinalItems);
}
```

Use your Object in your View.

View

```
@model Projectname.Models.QueryToReturn

<select>
      @foreach (var item in Model.projectGoal)
      {
           <option>@item.somevariable</option>
      }
</select>
```

I'm not sure if it's that easy to convert from your Entity list to your class. But it should work. That's the way I handle it.

Comment: This is what I have already done. My question was to make sure that I was doing it the right way.

Comment: @EhsanNajafi Oh sorry it was a misunderstanding on my part. That's a complicated question because there are always different ways to do something and if it works it's not wrong, maybe just not the easiest way. But regarding your question, it is a common way to handle it.